# Is there any book devoted to better decision making?

Tags: belief, rishi

Is there any book written by the sages devoted to better decision making in life ?

Comment: Read Upanishads, Bhagavad Gita, mahabharat, Ramayan .... and contemplate on them, you won't get better books than them.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer reading sundarakanda of ramayana, do read it regularly or do parayna, it has the power to push us in the right direction

Lord Hanuma faced many difficulties reaching lanka, so it pushes us in the right direction

remember one thing our previous lives karma and present day karma (what we are trying to do) between these one will win and it depends on us

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.